# Can I run nativescript app on iOS device connected to Windows machine

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, nativescript, device-emulation

I understand limitation when I want to run nativescript app on iOS **emulator** on my local Windows machine. But is it possible to run that app on iOS **device** that is connected to Windows with following CLI command?

```
tns run ios --device 123456789
```

If tns can generate, i.e. compile nativescript to iOS platform native files, what's missing in order to just run iOS app on connected iOS device?

Comment: No. You need the underlying xCode dependencies to actually perform the build and deployment to your device. NativeScript Playground is a great alternative that allows you to develop apps in an online editor and deploy to your device through a QR code (by downloading their Playground app from the App Store). They are just churning your app to Mac servers to perform the cloud builds.

Comment: Fair answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use [NativeScript Sidekick](https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-sidekick) on Windows to do a cloud build and deploy to a connected iOS device.